# Compiling errors while trying to link libraries in cross compilation

Tags: c++, c, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

**SOLVED -- Explanation at the end of the post**

I'm working on a project and right now I have to cross-compile two packages for ARM, a library and an application that depends on that library.

I have one .cmake file for both library and application and it seems to work except for the fact that whenever the compiling process reaches the linking phase, the compiler says it can't find some libraries and then shuts down.

I have checked and my system meets all the requirements for building these programs from source, however, there are a few things to know about the configuration of the projects.

As I'm cross-compiling, all the libraries I need must be the ARM versions of them, which is not a problem at all, but I think the way these libraries are provided is what is causing all the trouble. I'm just guessing here, because I can't think of any other reason that could happen.

So, I'm providing these libraries using the .cmake file, which looks something like this:

```sh
set( TC_PATH "/usr/bin/" )
set( ROOTFS_PATH "/home/pc/Desktop/projects/rootfs" )
set( CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX "/usr" )

set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )

set( CROSS_COMPILE arm-linux-gnueabihf- )

set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${TC_PATH}${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${TC_PATH}${CROSS_COMPILE}g++" )
set( CMAKE_LINKER "${TC_PATH}${CROSS_COMPILE}ld" )
set( CMAKE_AR "${TC_PATH}${CROSS_COMPILE}ar" )
set( CMAKE_OBJCOPY "${TC_PATH}${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy" )

set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY )

set( CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${ROOTFS_PATH} )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${ROOTFS_PATH}${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX}" )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${ROOTFS_PATH} )
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${ROOTFS_PATH}${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig/" )
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${ROOTFS_PATH} )

set( CAER_LOCAL_PREFIX ${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX} )
set( CAER_LOCAL_INCDIRS "${ROOTFS_PATH}${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX}/include/" )
set( CAER_LOCAL_LIBDIRS "${ROOTFS_PATH}/lib/;${ROOTFS_PATH}${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib/" )
```

So, as the file specifies, the directories where the libraries are kept are "${ROOTFS_PATH}/lib/" and "${ROOTFS_PATH}${CROSS_LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib/", which ultimately translates into "/home/pc/Desktop/projects/rootfs/lib/" and "/home/pc/Desktop/projects/rootfs/usr/lib" respectively.

This path is a bit unorthodox, but that's where the ARM libraries are at. The reason for this is that the "rootfs" directory contains the file system for a small Linux distribution that is meant to be run on embedded hardware, using an SD card for storage, and it already has everything it needs except for these two programs I'm having trouble to compile.

Since the libraries' directories are correct, I expected the compilation to go all well, but that was not the case. Instead, I got more than one error related to the libraries:

Compilation results:

```sh
[  7%] Linking C shared library libcaer.so
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/caer.dir/build.make:248: recipe for target 'src/libcaer.so.3.1.0' failed
make[2]: *** [src/libcaer.so.3.1.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:135: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/caer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/caer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, and this is what is driving me crazy, when the errors pop up they say that **/lib/libc.so.6** or whatever other library is missing, not that **/home/pc/Desktop/projects/rootfs/usr/lib/whatever** is missing.

From that, I guess that libraries are not being looked for in the correct directories, even though the correct ones are specified in the .cmake file.

I've successfully built these two programs before, but the only time I managed to do it I had to copy the specific libraries that weren't found into the specific path the compiler told me it was looking for them in.

This means I copied "/home/pc/Desktop/projects/rootfs/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a" into "/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a", and so on.

This approach is not an acceptable one, as I will probably have to give some other people instructions in order to have them compile the applications themselves, and copying libraries that already exist in some other place just because the compiler "ignores" them just doesn't feel right.

So, this is as far as I could get, I hope someone will be able to shed some light on the matter. Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE -- SOLVED**

So, in the end I was wandering through the cmake toolchain file documentation page (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) and I happened to spot one variable called "CMAKE_SYSROOT", which is optional and may be used if there is a sysroot other than that in the host system, like in this case. Hence, I tried setting the variable like this:

```sh
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${ROOTFS_PATH}")
```

And miraculously it worked; it stopped looking for the libraries in my root system (/lib/... , /usr/lib/...) so I guess those in the filesystem provided where the ones that were finally used and the compilation ended successfully, for both the library and the dependant application.

Comment: Please copy&paste the compilation output to the question **as text** instead of showing a screenshot. I suggest to set and export `LANG=C` before running the build steps to get English error messages.

Comment: From your `.cmake` file (snippet?) I can guess that you want to use `CAER_LOCAL_LIBDIRS` as the library location. Please show how the build target is defined and how you specify the libraries or library location (e.g. `target_link_directories(...)`). If it is not too much you might show the complete `CMakeLists.txt` and related files.

Comment: Please write up your solution as an answer.